# pyspark new column with conditions on existing column string (with special characters)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create a new column in pyspark dataframe based on the values(string with special character &) from one of the columns.

My existing column "Type" has either "Tea&Biscuits" or "Tea". If I find "Tea&Biscuits", then my new column "new_type" will have a string "BOTH" otherwise "tea

I tried as below. But the new column does not have BOTH. I tried as `"Tea\&Biscuits"` also but still did not work also.

```
df_new = df.withColumn("new_type", F.when(F.col("Type")=="Tea&Biscuits",F.lit("BOTH")).otherwise(F.col("Type")))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. That code does indeed set `new_type` to `'BOTH'` where `Type` is `'Tea&Biscuits'`

Comment: Yes thanks. I had to add trim function on that column and it works now. Thanks